# While vs If in Thread-Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I have two sets of code where i'm trying to print alphabets and numbers one after the other.One is using "while loop" and other is using "if".

```
public class Alphabets {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

          AN an= new AN(false);

          Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {             
                try {                       
                    an.Alpha();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });              

          Thread t2= new Thread(new Runnable() {                
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    an.numbers();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
        });                   
          t1.start();
          t2.start();
   }
}

class AN {  
  boolean flag; 
  AN(boolean flag) {
    this.flag=flag;
  }
  synchronized void Alpha() throws InterruptedException {       
    for(char i='A'; i<='Z';i++) {
        while(flag==false) { // I have replaced "while" with "if" in my second code         
          System.out.println(+i);
          notifyAll();
          flag=true;
        }           
        wait();         
    }
  }    
  synchronized void numbers() throws InterruptedException {     
    for(int i=1;i<=26;i++) {            
        while(flag==true) {// I have replaced "while" with "if" in my second code           
          System.out.println(+i);
          notifyAll();
          flag=false;
        }           
        wait();         
    }
  }     
}
```

Set 1 with "while" loop gives the following output :

65 1 66 2 67 3 68 4

Set 2 with "if" gives the following output :

65 1 67 3 69 5 71 7

Please note that 65 66 are the ascii codes for A,B etc.

Can anybody explain why these two codes are behave like this.I'm unable to figure it out.
Please explain in detail.

Comment: That code never outputs any letters, and the numbers are sequential whether I use a `while` or an `if`. Are you running the same code you posted?

Comment: Correct! it would print the ascii code for A as 65,B as 66 and so on.

Comment: @fgb I have edited the post with corresponding ascii values also.

Comment: There is no guarantee which method will get called first: `Alpha()` or `numbers()`.  If `numbers()` gets called first, its `int i` will get incremented without outputting anything.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, using if or while works exactly the same.voting to close.

Comment: Did you change *absolutely nothing* but the while-if between runs?  Using System.out to analyze concurrency issues is a bad idea.  Its effects on memory consistency and if it even prints things in the true order they happened are platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in [spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). This means any wait statement might spontaneously wake up without anyone actually calling notify. In this case the for loops advances another step without actually printing anything, because the flag is still in the wrong state.

Using if or while has no effect on the code itself, it just happens to trigger the actual issue more often.

The way to solve this is to loop wait till the state actually changed:

```
for(char i='A'; i<='Z';i++) {
    if(flag==false) {          
      System.out.println(+i);
      notifyAll();
      flag=true;
    } 
    while (flag == true) {    // spurious wakeup prevention      
      wait();         
    }
}
```

Comment: Err this doesn’t make any more sense than the other answers, and doesn’t address the actual question.

Comment: It actually explains the issue with a wiki link and provides a working solution. And it very much addresses the actual question.

Comment: Spurious Wakeups, if they happen at all on the combination of runtime and platform OP is using, are rare and unpredictable.  OP describes his problem as being deterministic and easily reproduced, if spurious wakeup is causing it something is very very wrong with his runtime or operating system.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue on my machine, so it has to do something with the OPs machine.

Comment: I agree this is not something reproducible. I think it's very far from clear spurious wakeup is a factor in this specific case. More likely there were additional changes besides changing while to if on the posted code posted that are needed to generate the second set of posted output.

Answer (score -1):

**`while loop`** is preferred in multi threading because it prevents from **`spurious wake up`** which means wait() method can return without notification from user thread, probably done by **`OS scheduler`**. In your case, I guess because of `spurious wakeup` `if() condition` is skiped and and again goes to `wait()`.